# Error in laravel 5.5 Class PaypalPayment does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am trying to make use of the following dependency in laravel 5.5

https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment

Error in laravel 5.5 Class App\Http\Controllers\PaypalPayment does not exist. I have not managed to call the PaypalPayment class. "use Paypalpayment" does not work.

[Capture del error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i235.png)

**Error:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-paypal - copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
}

/**
 * Instantiate a concrete instance of the given type.
 *
 * @param  string  $concrete
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
 */
public function build($concrete)
{
    // If the concrete type is actually a Closure, we will just execute it and
    // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
    // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
    if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
        return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

    // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    // an abstract type such as an Interface of Abstract Class and there is
    // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
    if (! $reflector->isInstantiable()) {
        return $this->notInstantiable($concrete);
    }

    $this->buildStack[] = $concrete;

    $constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

    // If there are no constructors, that means there are no dependencies then
    // we can just resolve the instances of the objects right away, without
    // resolving any other types or dependencies out of these containers.
    if (is_null($constructor)) {
        array_pop($this->buildStack);

        return new $concrete;
    }
```

Arguments
"Class App\Http\Controllers\PaypalPayment does not exist"

File Config/App

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
| framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
| any other location as required by the application or its packages.
|
*/

'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
| running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
| services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
|
*/

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloaded Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
| request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
| this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    Anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'     => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

'Paypalpayment'   => Anouar\Paypalpayment\Facades\PaypalPayment::class,

```
],
```

];

**File Class Paypalpayment in Vendor**

```html
<?php
namespace Anouar\Paypalpayment;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use PayPal\Api\Address;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Authorization;
use PayPal\Api\Capture;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCardToken;
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Links;
use PayPal\Api\Payee;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\PayerInfo;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentHistory;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Refund;
use PayPal\Api\RelatedResources;
use PayPal\Api\Sale;
use PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Transactions;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

class PaypalPayment
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Address
     */
    public function address()
    {
        return new Address;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Amount
     */
    public function amount()
    {
        return new Amount;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Details
     */
    public function details()
    {
        return new Details;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Authorization
     */
    public function authorization()
    {
        return new Authorization;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Capture
     */
    public function capture()
    {
        return new Capture;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\CreditCard
     */
    public function creditCard()
    {
        return new CreditCard;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\CreditCardToken
     */
    public function creditCardToken()
    {
        return new CreditCardToken;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument
     */
    public function fundingInstrument()
    {
        return new FundingInstrument;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Item
     */
    public function item()
    {
        return new Item;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\ItemList
     */
    public function itemList()
    {
        return new ItemList;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Links
     */
    public function links()
    {
        return new Links;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Payee
     */
    public function payee()
    {
        return new Payee;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Payer
     */
    public function payer()
    {
        return new Payer;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\PayerInfo
     */
    public function payerInfo()
    {
        return new PayerInfo;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Payment
     */
    public function payment()
    {
        return new Payment;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution
     */
    public function paymentExecution()
    {
        return new PaymentExecution;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\PaymentHistory
     */
    public function paymentHistory()
    {
        return new PaymentHistory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls
     */
    public function redirectUrls()
    {
        return new RedirectUrls;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Refund
     */
    public function refund()
    {
        return new Refund;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\RelatedResources
     */
    public function relatedResources()
    {
        return new RelatedResources;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Sale
     */
    public function sale()
    {
        return new Sale;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress
     */
    public function shippingAddress()
    {
        return new ShippingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Transactions
     */
    public function transactions()
    {
        return new Transactions;
    }

    /**
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Transaction
     */
    public function transaction()
    {
        return new Transaction;
    }


    /**
     * @param null $clientId
     * @param null $clientSecret
     * @param null $requestId
     * @return \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext
     */
    public function apiContext($clientId = null, $clientSecret = null, $requestId = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($clientId)) {
            $this->config['account']['client_id'] = $clientId;
        }

        if (!is_null($clientSecret)) {
            $this->config['account']['client_secret'] = $clientSecret;
        }

        $apiContext = new ApiContext($this->oAuthTokenCredential(), $requestId);

        $apiContext->setConfig([
            'mode' => $this->config['mode'],
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => $this->config['http']['connection_time_out'],
            'log.LogEnabled' => $this->config['log']['log_enabled'],
            'log.FileName' => $this->config['log']['file_name'],
            'log.LogLevel' => $this->config['log']['log_level']
        ]);

        return $apiContext;
    }

    /**
     * @param null $clientId
     * @param null $clientSecret
     * @return PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential
     */
    public function oAuthTokenCredential()
    {
        return new OAuthTokenCredential($this->config['account']['client_id'], $this->config['account']['client_secret']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the base URL
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return URL::to('/');
    }


    public static function getById($paymentId, $apiContext = null)
    {
        if (isset($apiContext)) {
            return Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
        }
        return Payment::get($paymentId);
    }

    /**
     * grape all payment details
     * @param $param
     * @param null $apiContext
     * @return \PayPal\Api\Payment
     */
    public static function getAll($param, $apiContext = null)
    {
        if (isset($apiContext)) {
            return Payment::all($param, $apiContext);
        }
        return Payment::all($param);
    }
}
```

**Config/App**

```html
<?php


    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'           => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'     => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'          => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
'Paypalpayment'   => Anouar\Paypalpayment\Facades\PaypalPayment::class,

    ],

];
```

**Controller edited**

```
class PaypalPaymentController extends Controller
```

{
    /*
    * Process payment using credit card
    */
    public function paywithCreditCard()
    {

```
    // ### Address
    // Base Address object used as shipping or billing
    // address in a payment. [Optional]
    $shippingAddress = PaypalPayment::shippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setLine1("3909 Witmer Road")
        ->setLine2("Niagara Falls")
        ->setCity("Niagara Falls")
        ->setState("NY")
        ->setPostalCode("14305")
        ->setCountryCode("US")
        ->setPhone("716-298-1822")
        ->setRecipientName("Jhone");

    // ### CreditCard
    $card = PaypalPayment::creditCard();
    $card->setType("visa")
        ->setNumber("4758411877817150")
        ->setExpireMonth("05")
        ->setExpireYear("2019")
        ->setCvv2("456")
        ->setFirstName("Joe")
        ->setLastName("Shopper");

    // ### FundingInstrument
    // A resource representing a Payer's funding instrument.
    // Use a Payer ID (A unique identifier of the payer generated
    // and provided by the facilitator. This is required when
    // creating or using a tokenized funding instrument)
    // and the `CreditCardDetails`
    $fi = PaypalPayment::fundingInstrument();
    $fi->setCreditCard($card);

    // ### Payer
    // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
    // Use the List of `FundingInstrument` and the Payment Method
    // as 'credit_card'
    $payer = PaypalPayment::payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
        ->setFundingInstruments([$fi]);

    $item1 = PaypalPayment::item();
    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setDescription('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setTax(0.3)
            ->setPrice(7.50);

    $item2 = PaypalPayment::item();
    $item2->setName('Granola bars')
            ->setDescription('Granola Bars with Peanuts')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(5)
            ->setTax(0.2)
            ->setPrice(2);


    $itemList = PaypalPayment::itemList();
    $itemList->setItems([$item1,$item2])
        ->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);


    $details = PaypalPayment::details();
    $details->setShipping("1.2")
            ->setTax("1.3")
            //total of items prices
            ->setSubtotal("17.5");

    //Payment Amount
    $amount = PaypalPayment::amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
            // the total is $17.8 = (16 + 0.6) * 1 ( of quantity) + 1.2 ( of Shipping).
            ->setTotal("20")
            ->setDetails($details);

    // ### Transaction
    // A transaction defines the contract of a
    // payment - what is the payment for and who
    // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
    // a `Payee` and `Amount` types

    $transaction = PaypalPayment::transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    // ### Payment
    // A Payment Resource; create one using
    // the above types and intent as 'sale'

    $payment = PaypalPayment::payment();

    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    try {
        // ### Create Payment
        // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
        // using a valid ApiContext
        // The return object contains the status;
        $payment->create(PaypalPayment::apiContext());
    } catch (\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        return response()->json(["error" => $ex->getMessage()], 400);
    }

    return response()->json([$payment->toArray()], 200);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to receive the best answers, you need to provide a code example as to what you have tried. Without the controller code calling this class (not a screenshot, typed code), there is no way for anyone to review it and assist.

Comment: thanks for your recomendation

Comment: Did you add the service provider and alias to your config/app.php file? For some reason it says Laravel 4, but that still applies for Laravel 5 unless they utilize auto discover (they don't). The use statement is referencing the Facade, so if that is not setup in your config, it will fail https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment

Comment: yes, 

If I added the php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider" and the configuration file paypal_payment.php was copied.

Comment: I also had already added the Alias and the provider

Comment: Did you cache your config file maybe? try php artisan config:clear. Maybe it is not picking up the Facade due to it beign added after a previous config cache.

You can also try referencing the class namespace itself by using Anouar\Paypalpayment\Facades\PaypalPayment vs. Paypalpayment. Just make sure to change all your method calls to PaypalPayment (second uppercase P)

Comment: Change the calls to the methods 'Paypalpayment' and 'PaypalPayments' and add the use Anouar \ Paypalpayment \ PaypalPayment; But I'm still the same.

Comment: use Anouar\Paypalpayment\Facades\PaypalPayment it did not work

Comment: Sorry, I had a routing error and did not call the route well. Then I clarify the details.